# Writing to Serial Port: Garbled if too fast

Tags: serial-port

I'm currently working on writing to a serial port to stimulate a device. The interface works in terms of strings of a specific form, terminated with a line-feed and carriage-return.

Baud rate is 9600, 8N1. We're using a USB-to-serial converter to create a virtual COM port.

The problem: This only works if I send the strings (such as "ABC123FF") one byte at a time, with at least a 5 millisecond delay between each byte.

Simple code that works (C#):

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace COM_tester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            if (port.IsOpen)
                port.Close();

            port.Open();
            Write(port, "ABC123FF", true);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("PORT: " + port.ReadExisting());
            port.Close();
            Console.In.Read();
        }

        static void Write(SerialPort port, string data, bool sleep)
        {
            foreach (char c in data)
            {
                port.Write(new string(c, 1));

                if (sleep)
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            port.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

But, calling the Write function without the sleep doesn't work at all. If anything gets echoed, it's just a couple question marks. Using port.WriteLine() has the same issue.

I've tried this with COM as well (CreateFile, WriteFile), with the same problem.

Interfacing with it in PuTTy works, but I'm guessing that's because PuTTy is sending bytes over as fast as I type them (which is greater than 10ms).

What's going on here?

EDIT: Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the device, so I won't be able to verify any suggested fixes.

Comment: If your simulated setup is correct, you don't need a delay between bytes.

Comment: Does the receiving side intentionally echo the received data? My guess is that the code on the other side is the one having the problem...

Comment: @Lynn: I believe the receiving side does intentionally echo the received data (though I'm not certain). I'm much more skeptical of my ability to configure and interface with these devices than I am of the devices themselves.

Comment: Did the device come with docs that stipulated 9600/8/N/1?

Comment: It came with docs that stipulated 8N1. The device has a configurable baud rate, and the docs imply that it defaults to 9600. I've tried setting it to a few different baud rates and testing whether it's mismatched.

Comment: Not using enough StopBits or guessing wrong at Parity are simple explanations.  You also seem to use RS-485, it needs to be properly terminated or you'll have electrical problems.  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: @HansPassant What is causing you to believe that he may be using RS-485?

Comment: Do the docs discuss flow control at all?

Comment: Hans is right; it's RS-485 (sorry for not mentioning that; part of not being familiar with a domain is not knowing which details are salient). @LynnCrumbling: The docs do not discuss flow control. I have so far left it at default: "None"

Comment: Nevertheless, very curious to know how @HansPassant derived that observation from the question :)

Comment: Just an hypothesis: if you are using 2-wire RS485 (which by definition is a half-duplex communication) with a serial device that automatically switches from send to receive, AND the remove device echoes what you send AND you're judging success by what gets echoed back, it makes sense that you have to leave gaps between characters - without the gaps the echoed characters won't reach the sending computer.

Comment: @fvu: Success isn't solely judged by echoed characters, but also by whether the device responds to the sent data (by updating its indications). The easiest test case is a string that tells it to display a set of numbers. Even when configuring the device to not echo sent characters, it does not respond to sent data if no delay is used. But it is 2-wire. =)

Comment: @fvu That makes a lot of sense. Christopher: to test this hypothesis, do you have the capacity to disable echo on the device?

Comment: By the way, I've never done rs-485, so I'm going to be turning into a pumpkin very soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56383/discussion-between-fvu-and-christopher-berman).

Comment: @ChristopherBerman
Are you using a loopback cable?
Isn't it just that the serial port hasn't transmitted the bytes yet over the wire when you call read()
I don't think Write() will block until the bytes are transmitted. Normally you wait until there is some data in the read buffer before you read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for something to come in before reading.
The device has no time to respond before you call ReadExisting.
Doesn't this work

```
Write(port, "ABC123FF", false);
Thread.Sleep(100)
Console.Out.WriteLine("PORT: " + port.ReadExisting());
```

Ideally you would use Read(buffer, offset, count) instead to wait for something to come in.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately I'm about three projects removed from the original codebase and original issue, so I can't verify if this fixes my problem. I'm convinced I was doing something wrong on the configuration side of the device (which was very niche and custom-built), as none of the guides or help seemed to fix the weird issues I was seeing.

Comment: Ah, crap. Didn't realize that the post was so old.